# Toggling Annotate line drawing mode instead of holding keys

Tags: customization, shortcut, grease-pencil, annotation

Is it possible to change the shortcuts for Annotate (what used to be Grease Pencil) to a toggle-type hotkey, instead of having to hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> for `Draw Straight Lines`?

It's the `gpencil.annotate` property in the keymap; as far as I'm concerned there's no 'toggle' option anywhere.

I've tried setting different shortcuts, both on mouse and keyboard, as well as enabling 'Wait for Input' but I can't seem to find a toggle key.

Ultimately I'd like this to be either a pie menu where you can quickly select a different drawing mode, or bound to single keys (like the numeral keys) so I can quickly switch without having to *hold* keys.